# How to get Analytics on this site? The SEO people say they are unable to install webmaster tools because the code isn't in the <head> section

Tags: seo, google-analytics

The SEO company keeps bugging me to put the Analytics code in the `<head>` section because they say:

"...the code isn't in the `<head>` section, I am unable to install webmaster tools, which is essential to us tracking keywords for the campaign. Could you please move the analytics code to the `<head>` section or paste the following code in the  section?"

How do I do that? Or is there a place in the Admin where this can be added and it would allow the SEO people to install the Webmaster tools?

**NEW INFO: Magento 2.1.0**

Update: I tried putting the code into:

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Open your theme for edit -> HTML Head
```

but it didn't include the Google Analytics code before the end HEAD tag so I put it at the bottom of:

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/myTHEME/MYtheme/my_THEME/templates/html/head.phtml
```

**Is this a good solution?**

Answer (score 1):

Try going to this part of the admin:

```
System->Configuration->Design->Head
```

and see if you can insert what you need in there

Comment: that's perfect and it works great in the 1.x.x version - I'm trying to put it into Magento 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides a system configuration called `Miscellaneous scripts`. You can assign your analytics JS code into it and it will add this JS code into head section.

Follow below steps to assign JS to `Miscellaneous scripts`.

1. Login to the admin panel
2. go to system>configuration
3. Click on the Design section on the left
4. Open the HTML Header group
5. And look for a text box labled “Miscellaneous scripts”

I hope it will help.

Comment: that's perfect and it works great in the 1.x.x version - I'm trying to put it into Magento 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1 `Miscellaneous scripts` configuration is rendering before the body closing tag and it's no longer in `Stores -> Configuration` section.

If you need to place the script into **`<head>`** tag you can place it in `Scripts and Style Sheets` section

> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Open your theme for edit -> HTML Head

This will be included before head closing tag in page HTML.

Comment: I did that on all levels - website, store and storefront and deleted ALL CACHE and re-indexed via SSH but the code has not been inserted before the closing /head tag. And the SEO people insist: So the head section of the website ends on line 50 in the source code. Currently the Google Analytics tracking code is in place at around line 121. I will need it to be pasted somewhere before /head and before line 50 in the source code.